# How can I query an xml file and save the result in another xml file

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am new with learning the possibilities of Linq to XML and I recently have found that I can query an xml like a data base (I am quite fascinated by it now).

My question is How can I query an xml file and save the result in another xml file?:

```
 string url = "employees.xml";

 XElement employees= XElement.Load(url);


 if (employees.Element("employee") != null)

 {

     var query = from f in employees.Element("employee").Elements("item").Take(10)

                 select new { Name = f.Element("name").Value, Surname= f.Element("surname").Value };


     foreach (var feed in query)

     {

        //here... I like to write the result in a different xml file, I tried the 
        //common 
        doc.save("xmlout.xml");


     }

 }
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this by creating an XDocument/XElement instance and then populating it with the results of your query (by passing the query to the constructor of the XDocument/XElement), and then saving that.

However, you might want to consider using an XSLT transformation instead, as that is really what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yap, XSLT would probably be the best way when you want to transform one XML document into another.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) article should help you solve your problem. Btw if you new up as XElement and then populate you can use the save method, instead of using anonymous types.